# Support for HLS in Kurento something as HLSEndpoint

Tags: gstreamer, kurento

We are trying to achieve HTTP live streaming through kurento Media Server-6.5, being a kurento GStreamer module something as HLSEndpoint as part of kms itself and not through some 3rd party server (e.g wowza or a nginx hls module).

It could be thought of as:

WebRtcEndpoint -> RTPEndpoint -> HLSEndpoint

where HLSEndpoint would be responsible for creating the .m3u8 playlist file and .ts media fragments of the live stream.

Sorry, I am a newbie with kurento and GStreamer and tried to search a lot around this and unfortunately did not find any help in this direction.

I have even tried [HLSConvertor](https://github.com/swarmnyc/HLSConvertor) hlsplugin to integrate in kms but unfortunately this module is not complete and does not fulfill the purpose.

Any help in this direction would be greatly appreciated.